# ionic4/react-router - IonBackButton does not appear

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, ionic4

I'm using Ionic4 to develop a hybrid mobile react.js app for Android, and am also using react-router-dom to handle navigation.

I have defined the app's routes using the `BrowserRouter` and `Route` components and can navigate forward and backward just fine using the `history` attribute injected in the components' `props`.

This is a sample app, where each route loads the same component, which has an `IonHeader` with `IonToolbar`, which, in turn, contains an `IonBackButton`.

When the app opens a new page, the back button is visible at the navigation bar for a brief period of time, before disappearing. According to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button/), `IonBackButton` is smart enough to determine when it must be visible, so I don't know if this is happening because Ionic's integration with react.js is still in beta, or because I did something wrong.

This is my app definition:

```
const App: React.FC = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <IonApp>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage} />
          <Route exact path="/foo" component={MainPage} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonApp>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

And this is the route component:

```
const MainPage: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = props => <>
    <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar color="primary">
        <IonBackButton goBack={() =>{}} />
      </IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
    <IonContent>
      <IonButton onClick={() => props.history.push("/foo")}>Navigate</IonButton>
    </IonContent>
</>
```

Why is the back button hidden after being visible? I have tried using a different component for each route, but the problem remais.

Answer (score 1):

Use defaultHref prop in IonBackButton:

```
<IonToolbar>
  <IonButtons slot='start'>
    <IonBackButton defaultHref='/' />
  </IonButtons>
  <IonTitle>Back Button</IonTitle>
</IonToolbar>
```